# Game crashes to desktop in Windows 10 Boot Camp MacBook Air 2015 11" (Intel HD 6000)

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, games, macos

I installed windows 10 on my MBA 2015 11" with Boot Camp, did everything, installed the drivers using the support software. But, whenever i tried to open a game ( far cry 2) it crashed.

Things I've done:

1. Installed direct x 9 . Didnt work
2. Installed every required .NET library and VC redistribution. Didn't work.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What does CTD mean? In general I found it useful to explain the problem you are facing in detail. And not just to say "I be tried everything" but to list the things you've tried and what their result was. Otherwise people will just recommend the same things again

Comment: @patrix CTD means Crashes to desktop

Comment: @patrix ive edited the question

Comment: @Anon Have you checked the application log in the Event Viewer? If the game is crashing there should be log entries there that should give you more information about why the game is crashing.

Comment: Is there a log for the game?  Have you contacted their support?  The crashing could have nothing to do with the Mac (hardware) at all and is simply a fault of the game or setting within Win10.

Comment: @Alistair McMillan  if the event logger records something soon as it crashes under windows logs>applications then its says "Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2017-06-01T12:45:03Z. Error Code: 0x80041318.". (idk how to use it) as soon as FC2 crashes.

Comment: @anon I don't think that'd be it. There should be entries that list the source as the executable name of your game (I think it's simply farcry2.exe).

Comment: @Alistair McMillan no entries like that

Comment: @anon Are you launching the game from Steam, or independently?

Comment: @Alistair McMillan yes independently

Comment: guys WTF now it worked when i installed it on an external hdd

Answer (score 1):

Just a little bit of research on Far Cry 2 we get the following:

[System Requirements](http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=85&game=Far%20Cry%202):

- 2GB RAM
- 256MB VRAM
- Windows XP 32bit

Your MacBook Air came with either 4 or 8GB of RAM.  Regardless, if you are running Boot Camp with a 32bit version of Windows (XP, Vista, 7, 8, 10, whatever), the most RAM you are going to be able to access is 3.5GB

Integrated Graphics:
Intel HD 6000 uses up to 1.5GB of *shared memory*.  From [Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204349):

> Apple computers using newer versions of Intel HD Graphics as the
>   primary GPU dynamically allocate up to 1.5 GB of system memory.

So, you are at a max of 2GB RAM.  Win10 requires a minimum of 1GB of RAM with 2GB recommended.  You're at the very edge of what the system calls for.  Additionally, it specifies ***Windows XP 32bit***.  If you are running a 64bit OS, there's no telling how this will function, if at all and there's no compatibility statement that I could find with respect to Windows 10.

However, from a [discussion forum](https://www.gog.com/forum/far_cry_series/far_cry_2_on_a_macbook_air) there's this little quote (re:  FC2 on MBA w/ HD3000):

> I can say with 100% certianty that a vid card like yours being intel
>   onboard junk will *NOT* run the game in any way. Infact i suggest
>   against buying anything made in the last 5 years and trying to play.

and

> I *highly* doubt that. The only way to be sure is to try, but I think
>   you'd be wasting time and money.

So, you may get it to work in Boot Camp under Windows XP 32bit but because of the architecture of the MBA, it may not be worth the effort.

Comment: But this actually worked without any flaws when: I used an external hard drive, installed windows 8 pro 64 bit with the help of https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiK_aair9HTAhXHrI8KHcoiCZUQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarkthetech.com%2Fhow-to-boot-camp-usb-3-0-external-hard-drive%2F&usg=AFQjCNHvYK5ItjBB4ATV4mTNy7xHTiYKjg&sig2=LpDUupHJAk1NoYZji1h1TA        and installed bootcamp drivers from  http://download.digiex.net/Drivers/Bootcamp/AppleBcUpdate6.0.6171-01.April.2016.zip.  and now i have windows 10 internally and im using the same driver.

Comment: @Allan Everything you've said here might cause bad performance. It shouldn't cause the game to crash.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan - I'm basing this on my research which is why I put the very last sentence in my post:  *"you may get it to work in Boot Camp under Windows XP 32bit but because of the architecture of the MBA, it may not be worth the effort."*

Comment: @Allan Fair enough. I'm just saying anon asked why his game is crashing you've answered a totally different question ("Should I even try running Far Cry 2 on my MacBook Air?"). :P

BTW Here is someone using Far Cry 2 as a benchmarking tool and getting okay (not great) frame rates on the same MacBook Air model. http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/feature-macbook-air-vs-macbook-pro-battle-apple-s-13-inch-notebooks/performance-benchmarking-3

Comment: @Allan there is no doubt that this game cannot run in my macbook and ive played it already with no flaws at all ,evrything smooth, ( i said that in my previous comment) but idk after i installed windows 10 on internal sdd  and used the same drivers that worked before while on an external hardware. (i played the game).It just crashed. The only difference now is ive put windows internally.

Comment: @ Allan its working now when i installed it on an external hdd can you tell me whats happening in here?

Comment: @Alistair McMillan its working now when i installed it on an external hdd can you tell me whats happening in here?

Comment: @Anon What version of Windows do you have on the external drive? Is it Windows 8 again? Perhaps the problem is Windows 10. Maybe the game needs to run in compatibility mode on Windows 10. I still think there should be entries in the Event Viewer if the game is actually launching and crashing. That's the only way to work out exactly what is happening.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan no i mean windows is in my internal drive but only the game is in external